# Undeclared identifier `shigh`; tradingview (pinescripts)

Tags: pine-script

This code works well in `//@version=3` of pinescripts.

I would like to convert to `//@version=4` but the following error:

> Undeclared identifier 'shigh'

This is the code:

```
is_newbar(res) =>
    t = time(res)
    change(t) != 0 ? 1 : 0


shigh = is_newbar("D") ? high : (high > shigh[1] ? high : nz(shigh[1], high))
```

What can be the issue that cause this error?

Answer (score 1):

welcome to stack overflow 
The issue is you are using `pinescript-version > 2` which restricts access to undeclared variables.

---

Here is your fixed code

```
//@author=lucemanb
//@version=4
study("Declare Varia")
is_newbar(res) =>
    t = time(res)
    change(t) != 0 ? 1 : 0
shigh = high
shigh := is_newbar("D") ? high : (high > shigh[1] ? high : nz(shigh[1], high))
plot(shigh)
```

Enjoy